# How to add iis web site name in Additional appcmd.exe commands of azure pipeline iis deployment task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, appcmd

I am using azure release pipeline, an i am stuck in IIS web app manage task.
I want to add dynamically IIS website name in Additional appcmd.exe command, but I am not getting how to add it

azure IIS deployment task

[image]

I wanted to add a website name without using a hardcore value (myApsSiteName) in Additional appcmd.exe command, for example,

I dont want this way -->delete **myApsSiteName**

I want this way --> delete **Website name**

How to add website name without using hardcore website name value?

Comment: Can you use variables? Where is the name coming from?

Comment: How to use it in input box?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch